# Загрузка картинок в ImageView

Tags: url, imageview, android-imageview

Здравствуйте, есть ImageView,  с сервера поступает ссылка на картинку, нужно чтобы она отображалась в ImageView , как это правильно реализовать  . Желательно кратко и с пояснениями (я новичок )

Comment: Добавьте код как ссылка поступает с сервера. Чтобы была хоть отправная точка

Comment: В качестве сервиса использую Firebase

Comment: @НикитаВасильченко К сожалению сейчас не могу , но она поступает по типу, TextView.setText(......setValet());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого очень подходит [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Объяснение к примеру

```
    Context context;
    load(....) - ссылка к картинке
    placeholder(....) -пока картинка не будет загружена, показывает это изображения
    error(....) - выводит изображение в случае ошибки(неудачи)
    into(imageView) -  сам ImageView куда вывести надо
```

Сам пример

```
Picasso.with(context).load(item.getEmblems().getX64().getWot()).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).error(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(vh.imageView);
```

Как видим всего одна строчка кода, очень удобная библиотека.

Comment: Не понял куда указать ссылку

Comment: load(тут ваша ссылка)

Comment: Спасибо , я так понимаю нужно подгрузить библиотеку ?

Comment: да, у себя в  build.gradie использую
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

Comment: Большое спасибо .............

Comment: обращайтесь))))

Comment: Помимо Picasso, существует еще библиотека Glide. Выполняет те же функции, но позволяет также кэшировать и менять размер картинок. У Glide в ряде случаев меньшее потребление памяти. Какую библиотеку решать конечно вам. Но пока не до конца внедрили Picasso рекомендую посмотреть это сравнение: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en
К сожалению на английском, но там есть картинки и графики.

Comment: @ВиталийРобиновский у меня возникла ошибка при запуске .
логи 
Context must not be null.

Comment: ну так context вы должны свой подключить. В активити this, во фрагменте getActivity() или getContext(), точно не помню